# Deregistering AngularJs (1.x) $rootScope event listener does not clean up $$listeners?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular.js (1.x).

It appears that deregistering event listeners on `$rootScope` does not remove the listeners from the `$$listeners` property array. Am I missing something?

Here I use `$scope.$root` to access `$rootScope`.

1. Get list of listeners.

```
> $scope.$root.$$listeners  
  Object  
    $locationChangeSuccess: Array[1]  
    __proto__: Object
```

2. Add `cat` listener on `$rootScope`.

```
> var dog = $scope.$root.$on("cat", function() {});  
undefined
```

3. Verify `cat` listener added.

```
> $scope.$root.$$listeners
  Object
    $locationChangeSuccess: Array[1]
    cat: Array[1]
    __proto__: Object
```

4. Deregister, by calling `dog` function.

```
> dog()  
undefined
```

5. Check if `cat` listener is empty / removed. Nope.

```
> $scope.$root.$$listeners
  Object
    $locationChangeSuccess: Array[1]
    cat: Array[1] // ???? I would expect this to be 0 now
    __proto__: Object
```

6. In case it's a unapplied digest cycle problem.

```
> $scope.$root.$apply()  
undefined
```

7. Check if `cat` listener is empty / removed. Nope.

```
> $scope.$root.$$listeners
  Object
    $locationChangeSuccess: Array[1]
    cat: Array[1] // Nope.
    __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

So the event is deregistered. However, the `$$listeners` array property is not purged. Normally the `$$listeners` array property will contain the callback function, but after deregistration it is replaced with null.

This behavior is concerning because as you register / deregister listeners the array will continue to grow. I'm not sure if it is garbage collected at some point.

```
> $scope.$root.$$listeners["cat"]
[null, null, function]
```